# Where has "invert colors" gone in the new MS Paint?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

I'm wondering where the old "invert colors" feature from MS Paint has gone. My new version of MS Paint 6.1 doesn't seem to have this feature?

Comment: What is your new version?

Comment: Paint v6.1 (newer Windowses)

Comment: I believe the shortcut still is Ctrl+I or Ctrl+Shft+I

Answer (score 36):

### Right-click!

Actually, the option still exists, but it's not found on the ribbon. You can only find it when **right-clicking** an image:

[image: Rightclick]

The result:

[image: Everything inverted]

If you select everything or nothing, the entire image is inverted. Else, only the selection gets inverted:

[image: Rightclick on selection]

The result:

[image: Partial inversion]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.